# Weak convergence to a constant implies convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

If on some probability space the random variables $X_1, \dots, X_n$ with distributions $\mu_n$ convergence weakly to the constant random variable $c \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e.

$ \int f \, d \mu_n \to \int f \, d \delta_c  = f(c) $ for all bounded, continuous $f$
or equivalently
$E[f(X_n)] \to E[f(c)] = f(c)$ for all bounded, continuous $f$,
then $X_n \to c$ in probability

I would like to proof this without using convergence in distribution or the Portmanteau theorem, if possible.

I noted that
$\int f \, d \mu_n - f(c) = \int (f - f(c) ) \, d \mu_n \to 0$

Any ideas on how to continue, or other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You can use that convergence in probability of $X_n\to X$ is equivalent to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathrm{E}[|X_n-X|\wedge 1]=0$.